# how i can don't apply plugin to id if he not exists

Tags: javascript, exists

Javascript how i can don't apply plugin to id if he not exists.

```
$('#wyswig_comment').wyswig();

// Initialization   
$.fn.wyswig = function(options)
{               
    if (isiOS() || detectAndroid() || detectAndroidWebKit()) return false;              
    var obj = new Construct(this, options);         
    obj.init();     
    return obj;
};
```

If #wyswif_comment not exists in DOM in IE i have error. How check in initializtion function hav element with this id or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your code with:

```
// Initialization   
$.fn.wyswig = function(options)
{
      if(!this.length) return;
```

`this` inside a JQUery plugin function refers to the matched selectors. If the length of the matched element equals zero, exit the function using `return`.